# Как создать кастомную строку поиска

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет. Хочу создать кастомную строку поиска на карте, как, например, на maps.yandex.ru, но не особо представляю, как это правильно реализовать. Она должна создаваться как кастомный элемент через JS, или, возможно, можно править стили стандартной строки? Если через JS, то буду премного благодарен за пример кода.

Comment: речь про адресную строку браузера?

Comment: Про строку поиска на карте.

Comment: приведите пример

Comment: Стандартная строка выглядит [вот так](https://i.imgur.com/YJlammX.png), а кастомная - [примерно вот так](https://i.imgur.com/YNUaxz1.png). Во всяком случае, я подразумевал именно это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать по аналогии с примером для другого элемента управления https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/zoom_layout

Документация: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#control.SearchControl__param-parameters.options.layout